# understanding CLR/System.IO.FileNotFoundException "Could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies"

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have an issue with using `System.Text.Json` insinde my C# class library, which is a SolidWorks addin. It is probably an instance of DLL hell as described [here](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/).

Since [this approach](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38782#issuecomment-659064836) does not work, I might be able to figure something out if I understand a bit more about this issue. Maybe someone can help?

First - my code.

My 'csproj' file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <!-- general stuff -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net48</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- references: the top two are SolidWorks API (needed for making a SolidWorks addin -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="com.solidworks.core" Version="29.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="com.solidworks.tools" Version="21.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- In order to have the addin available within SolidWorks,
       it's dll needs to be registered in the codebase. For convenience
       we automatically register on build and unregister on clean. -->
  <Target Name="Register" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /codebase" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Unregister" BeforeTargets="BeforeClean">
    <Exec Command="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe &quot;$(TargetPath)&quot; /u" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The relevant parts of my `cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using SolidWorks...; // all the SolidWorks usings required

namespace SwxAddin
{
    [Guid("acb6f17b-9738-4f11-a324-30e05625ff89")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class SwxAddinImpl : ISwAddin
    {
        // will be called on addin load in SolidWorks
        public bool ConnectToSW(object swx, int addinId)
        {
            var jsonText = "{ \"foo\": { \"bar\": 2 } }";
            var doc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText); // exception occurs

            return swx != null;
        }

        // will be called on addin unload in SolidWorks
        public bool DisconnectFromSW() { return true; }

        // This is run when registering the dll. It writes some stuff into the
        // SolidWorks registry to make the addin available.
        [ComRegisterFunction]
        protected static void RegisterFunction(Type type) { ... }

        // This is run when unregistering the dll. It removes the stuff from the
        // SolidWorks registry that was written into it by RegisterFunction.
        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        protected static void UnregisterFunction(Type type) { ... }
    }
}
```

When I run SolidWorks after building (and thus, registering my dll in the codebase) and debug it, I get a runtime error on

```
var doc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText);
```

saying

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.IO.FileNotFoundException An
> exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
> System.Text.Json.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe,
> Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
> one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

. As mentioned above, I did try adding

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to my csproj file, resulting in the following `.dll.config` file in my bin/Debug folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but the runtime error still occurs.

So I'd like to actually understand the issue instead of just following cooking recipes. Here are some things I tried and thoughts:

1. The error says the issue is inside `System.Text.Json.dll`. I understand it so that the file `System.Text.Json.dll`, which lies in location `A`, expects a file `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` of version `4.0.4.1` in location `B`, but in location `B` there is a different version of file `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` (or no file of that name at all).

=> **Can anyone tell me which locations `A` and `B` we are talking about?** Is it a certain folder? Is it the GAC? In case it is the GAC, are we actually talking about files, or something else?

2. I checked the (for me) most probable location, the folder `$myProjectPath\bin\Debug\net48`. There I can find (amongst others) both dlls `System.Text.Json.dll` and `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll`. I opened both in some decompilation tool to check their versions and the versions of their references. This is what I found:

- `System.Text.Json.dll` has version `6.0.0.2` and references `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` of version `6.0.0.0`.
- `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` has version `6.0.0.0`.

=> **So the required version and the present version of `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` do align.** Why do I then get the error? Doesn't this just mean that location `A` and `B` are NOT `$myProjectPath\bin\Debug\net48`? **Or is the referenced version ignored under some circumstances? What kind of cirumstances?**

3. I built a standalone console app, just using `System.Text.Json` and containing the two lines

   `var jsonText = "{ \"foo\": { \"bar\": 2 } }";`

   `var doc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(jsonText);`

inside it `Main` method. No runtime error occurs there. **So SolidWorks must be the culprit somehow**, even if it is not mentioned in the runtime error message.

4. [This article](https://michaelscodingspot.com/assemblies-load-in-dotnet/) covers dll hell and gives suggestions for troubleshooting. I checked the modules (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) in Visual Studio. It turns out that just before the error occurs

- `System.Text.Json` version `6.0.0.0` is already loaded (from my `$myProjectPath\bin\Debug\net48` folder).
- `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` is not loaded.

=> **But if `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` has not been loaded before,** why does `System.Text.Json` want to load version `4.0.4.1` instead of the version specified in its own references (`6.0.0.0`)? **Where does the `4.0.4.1` come from?**

Comment: Adding a handler to the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event is one way to go - that both lets you inspect the details of what assemblies it tries to load, and you can manually load the required assembly from any location you choose.

Comment: Where the CLR searches for assemblies is straight-forward for net48, first it looks in the GAC and next it looks in the directory where the .exe is stored.  The install directory for SolidWorks in this case.  The addin dll is special, SolidWorks can find it thanks to the Regasm.exe /codebase registration, but that does not otherwise make help the CLR find any other dlls in the same directory.  The incorrect config file cannot hurt, the CLR only considers a .exe.config file.

Comment: @HansPassant Does that mean: All assemblies that SolidWorks needs on its own will be loaded from the SolidWorks exe folder in the version that SolidWorks asks for (here probably `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` version `4.0.4.1`), and then, EVEN THOUGH a given assembly asks for another version than SolidWorks (here: version `6.0.0.0`), it will still try to retrieve the version that has already been loaded (here `4.0.4.1`)? If so, is this really intended? Or does it have to do with messed up bindings (see [here](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/)), i.e. bugs?

Comment: SolidWorks is not a .net program, so "on its own" does not apply.

Comment: @HansPassant Even though, SolidWorks still makes something load `.dll`s. Am I on the right track with my guess (that, if an assembly `A` has already been loaded in version `X`, and an assembly `B` is being loaded that has a reference to `A` version `Y`, the `Y` will be ignored but instead looked for version `X`), or is it completely different?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to M Kloster's comment, I could work around the issue by manually loading the assembly - although this unfortunately does not help understanding the issue.

First I inserted the line

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
```

into the `ConnectToSW` method (as first line).

Then I implemented `MyResolveEventHandler` like so:

```
private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var nameCompilerServicesUnsafe = "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe";
    if (args.Name == nameCompilerServicesUnsafe + ", Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
    {
        var assemblyPath = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;
        if (Path.GetFileName(assemblyPath) == "System.Text.Json.dll")
        {
            var assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
            var pathCompilerServicesUnsafe = Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, nameCompilerServicesUnsafe + ".dll");
            if (File.Exists(pathCompilerServicesUnsafe))
                return Assembly.LoadFile(pathCompilerServicesUnsafe);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now, whenever an assembly cannot be loaded by the automatic mechanism, `MyResolveEventHandler` will be called.

Here I just check if it is `System.Text.Json.dll` trying to load `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` version `4.0.4.1`, and if yes, I return the assembly `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` from `System.Text.Json.dll`'s location folder.

Strangely, this allowed me to confirm that the `System.Text.Json.dll` trying to load `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` version `4.0.4.1` really is the one located in my `$myProjectPath\bin\Debug\net48` folder. Which makes no sense to me, as the decompilation tool told me that the file `$myProjectPath\bin\Debug\net48\System.Text.Json.dll` references `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` version `6.0.0.0`, not `4.0.4.1`.

And as I said in my question, the issue does not occur outside of SolidWorks (e.g. in a standalone console app). So SolidWorks must somehow interfere in the (automatic) assembly resolving mechanism, maybe redirecting bindings? Very mysterious... Is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 0):

my scenario: one main console app project and one library project.

In the end, they had both to include the new Reference "System.Text.Json.dll" (in the References section from each project)and its dependencies (for utilizing .Net frm 4.8), compile everything and execute.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).